# Who is responsible for leaking my personal information to companies?

Tags: privacy, data-leakage

[image]
Lets say I have a couple of friends who I have in my address book and of course they saved me in theirs. There might be the obvious information about me like my *phone number* and my *email address* but maybe even more, like my *sex, birthday, second email address, work address, private address* and so on, depending on how organized my friends are.

When one of my friends installs an app on his/her mobile phone that has permissions to **read their contacts**, that app (like Facebook/Whatsapp or Google/Apple itself) will most probably grab all the information it can get, upload it to their servers and might match it to other information. At least I have no way of controlling it.
Now some company has all the information about me (which I carefully protected) perfectly arranged and preformatted by my friend or collegue, **without my consent**.
The person installing the app of course signed away their privacy rights but not mine!

So my question is: **Who is responsible for this unauthorized exchange of my personal data** [Update] **in Germany?** [/Update]

Do I have to sue my friend/collegue for adding me to their address book and giving it away so easily or is the company that grabs information to be held responsible?

*I asked the same question on the Android forum but it was called off topic. I hope it's ok to ask the same question again here.*

Comment: It's the company that is illegally obtaining and processing your personal records. Your friend was lacking the security awareness, but I'm not aware of any country where it's a crime.

Comment: "which I carefully protected" -- if telling it to your idiot friends can be considered careful protection ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting legal advice, which not only may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction but also from case to case, and so should be obtained from a qualified legal practitioner in the appropriate jurisdiction rather than from the Internet where the well-meaning and logical opinions you receive on the matter may leave you more ill-advised than if you hadn't asked at all.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ You say "illegally"...What  specific law are they breaking, and do you have case law that shows that this law is in fact interpreted this way by the courts?

Comment: @xander of course I have, see for example 'Data Protection Directive' (art. 30 is the most adequate).

Comment: @Xander you might be right. But laws are a part of information security. And many questions need different answers for different countries. I don't see that as a reason against the question.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ There are a number of exclusions and remedies provided there.  Has any company to date, been found liable for this specific behaviour by a court of law?  Additionally, this law is E.U. specific.  It's irrelevant to the rest of the world, full stop.

Comment: @Xander any law is irrelevant to the rest of the world. The national implementations are far more specific.

Comment: @sir_brickalot Generally speaking, we consider virtually all legal question off-topic for this reason.  That, and there are a far to many armchair lawyers who will happily give you answers that make sense to them, but don't account for the nuances of how law actually works.  Which, of course, also varies by jurisdiction.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ This is why over-reaching statements like "*It's the company that is illegally obtaining and processing your personal records*" are materially incorrect.

Comment: If it's off topic here, where is it on-topic?

Answer (score 7):

It's not an *unauthorised* exchange unless you make your friends sign NDAs before giving them your contact details. Without that, there's an implicit authorisation for your friends to make reasonable use of the data you've given them, which includes uploading it to third-party websites. So it's *your* responsibility, for giving out data that you want to be held safe from disclosure without first getting an NDA in place. Treat your own confidential data in the same way as you would any other confidential data, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: This argument may not be valid in the context of EU data protection law! Third-party websites should not be processing personal data without consent of the data subject.

Comment: Yes, but "I have a friend called Bob whose phone number is xxx-xxx-xxxx" is _my_ personal data as well as Bob's, and I can give consent for it to be processed.

Comment: @MikeScott it probably depends on the jurisdiction - at least in EU, you can give the information  "I have a friend called Bob whose phone number is xxx-xxx-xxxx" and your consent to some company, but according to EU data protection laws for most usages of this information they still need to obtain consent from Bob that *they* can use the information, no matter from where they got the information, even if the source person or company had full permission from Bob.

Comment: No, **your** phone number is your personal data, Bob's phone number is **Bob's** personal data.

Comment: The great thing about implied consent (and expectations of privacy) is they're based on custom. This of course varies by jurisdiction, and for that matter the law doesn't necessarily reflect what typical people *actually* expected or intended to authorise. It used to be that "please don't give my email address to spammers for your own personal gain" was implicit in exchanging contact details, maybe now it isn't. The notion that all information received can be passed on unless expressly prohibited has at least the benefit of simplicity, although that doesn't make it true in all jurisdictions.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ While that may be true in your head, do you have any documented examples of courts of law agreeing with your position?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Please add some sources for your statements to make it a good answer. Otherwise it is just an opinion.